# Copy and Rename File VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I need to move a file with a name based off of a date to another folder.

The file structure is:
**Source:** `\\network_location\folder\Filename_09-11-2012.txt`

**Destination:** `C:\Dump\Filename.txt`

The source file is always 1 day behind. I am looking to rename the file while copying it.
The code I am trying to use is:

```
Sub Copy_And_Rename()
    Name "\\network_location\folder\Filename_"+Month(Now())+"-"+Day(Now()-1)+"-"+Year(Now())+".txt" As "C:\Dump\Filename.txt"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use File Scripting Object instead? http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/filesystemobject.html

Answer (score 27):

You can copy and rename a file with the `FileSystemObject` like this:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
' First parameter: original location\file
' Second parameter: new location\file
objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Test\folder1\name1.txt", "C:\Test\folder2\name2.txt"
```

Comment: Third parameter: overwrite. The default is set to True. If this parameter is set to False and the destination file allready exists there will occur an error.

Answer (score 0):

Code to copy and rename file

```
sourceFilePath = "C:\filePath\source.xlsx"
destinationFilePath = "C:\filePath\destination.xlsx"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFile sourceFilePath, destinationFilePath
```