# vbs copy and rename file

Tags: vbscript, file-rename, file-copying

I'm trying to create a sub in VBScript to move an copy a file. I've tried a few different approaches that I found on here, as well as some other sites. I have the following working.

```
dim SEVO_XML_PATH 'File path to Sevo xml file
dim SEVO_BACKUP 'File path for sevo's backup location
SEVO_XML_PATH="xml\Database.xml"
SEVO_BACKUP="backup\"   

sub BackupSevo()
    If FSO.fileExists(SEVO_XML_PATH)=true then
        FSO.copyFile SEVO_XML_PATH, SEVO_BACKUP
    else
        msgbox("Sevo XML not found." & vbnewline & "Please contact Engineering.")
    end if
end sub
```

However I want to append the date to the end of the file name. When I add the name of the file being pasted like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393389/copy-and-rename-file-vbscript)...

```
backupName = "Database_" & date & ".xml"
FSO.copyFile SEVO_XML_PATH, SEVO_BACKUP & backupName
```

This gives me a "Path not Found" error. I've tried copying the  the file then using moveFile to rename it, but I got the same error.

```
FSO.copyFile SEVO_XML_PATH, SEVO_BACKUP
dim backupName
backupName = "Database_" & date & ".xml"
FSO.moveFile SEVO_BACKUP & "Database.xml", SEVO_BACKUP & backupName
```

I tried a method that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683373/copy-and-rename-oldest-file-using-vbs) to create an object to hold the file, then using the name property to change the name.

```
set sevoXML=FSO.getFile(SEVO_XML_PATH)
sevoXML.copy SEVO_BACKUP
set sevoXMLBackup=FSO.getFile(SEVO_BACKUP & "Database.xml")
sevoBackup.name=backupName
```

But I get the error "Invalid procedure call or argument" on the last line.

Any ideas, on either fixing one of these methods, or using a different one?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` returns the date seperated by backslash. Just like a folder structure in windows. So you are actually trying to write to folder:

```
/backup/Database_06/29/2016.xml
```

And you don't have a folder names `Database_06` and `29`. Format the date to change the backslashes to underscores or something:

```
backupName= "Database_" & replace(date, "/", "_") & ".xml"
```